# ファイルをblobの形で読み込みたい

Tags: javascript

javascriptは初心者なのですが、
サンプルコードなどを組み合わせながらwebアプリを作っています。
その中でのファイル読み込みについての質問です。

htmlで

```
<input type="file" class="input_02_file" multiple/>
```

と書き、.js内で

```
var B = doc.querySelector(".input_02_file").files
```

とするとblob型のファイルリストがBに入ります。

しかし、毎回ファイル指定する必要があり面倒です。
なので、スクリプトと同じディレクトリにファイルを置き、読み込めたらと考えました。
希望はBが自動で読み込まれることなのですが、できるでしょうか。

いろいろ調べてみましたが、分からず質問させていただきました。
ヒントでも頂ければ幸いです。宜しくお願い致します。

#### 追記

コメントありがとうございます。アプリは、画像を `readAsDataURL()` でいくつか読み込み、それをスライダーで切り替えるイメージです。
初期状態で画像のサンプルを読み込みたいです。
blob型かFileインスタンスを絶対パス(`".images/sample.png"`)から作成できれば、上の関数で画像を読めるのですが。

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25046301/convert-url-to-file-or-blob-for-filereader-readasdataurl
この辺りが参考になるかと思い、読んでいます。

Comment: `<input type="file">` で選択するようなクライアント側のファイルを読み込みたいなら、それをサーバー上のスクリプトと同じディレクトリに置くというのは無理な話では？どんなWebアプリを作ろうとしているのか書いていただけると、想像しやすいのですが・・・。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。アプリは、画像をreadAsDataURL()でいくつか読み込み、それをスライダーで切り替えるイメージです。初期状態で画像のサンプルを読み込みたいです。blob型かFileインスタンスを絶対パス(".images/sample.png")から作成できれば、上の関数で画像を読めるのですが。。
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25046301/convert-url-to-file-or-blob-for-filereader-readasdataurl
この辺りを読んでおります。

Answer (score 1):

サーバー側に用意しておいたサンプルデータをBlobとして読み込みたい、ということですね。

XMLHttpRequest では `xhr.responseType` に `blob` を指定することで、Blobとしてレスポンスを取り出せるようです。

エラー処理などを省いた最低限のコードとしてはこんな感じでしょうか。

```js
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("GET", "https://i.imgur.com/rjI42fW.png", true);
req.responseType = "blob";

req.onload = function(e) {
  // e.target or req
  var blob = e.target.response;
  document.write('<img src="' + window.URL.createObjectURL(blob) + '">');
};

req.send();
```

今回は大丈夫だと思いますが、XHRなのでCORSの制約を受けます。対象のリソースが別オリジンにある場合は、適切なヘッダを出力してください。

#### 参考

- [Sending and Receiving Binary Data - Web APIs | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data)
- [javascript - Getting BLOB data from XHR request - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8022425/getting-blob-data-from-xhr-request)
  arraybufferを経由した方法も載っていますが、最近のブラウザならblobでいけるようです。

Comment: e.responseでは取得できずでした。req.responseで取得できました

Comment: サンプル故の端折ったコードとは思いますが、他の方が誤解する可能性があるので念の為、指摘しておきます。
`document.write` を使用していますが、`DOMContentLoaded` 後に実行されると画面がクリアされる問題があります。
コードの原形を保つなら、`insertAdjacentHTML` か `innerHTML` を使う事で解決できると思います。